# Ancestor level binding not working in MenuItem command

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, icommand, findancestor

We have use the hierarchical template to populate the menuitem

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:MenuViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>    

    <Grid>
        <!--Initialize the Menu-->
        <Menu Name="Part_Menu" ItemsSource="{Binding MenuCollection}" Background="#E5E5E5" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Menu.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItemCollection}">
                    <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Header}" />
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                            <Setter Property="CommandParameter"  Value="{Binding Header}"/>
                            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                            <Setter Property="Command"
                                    Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MenuViewModel}, AncestorLevel=2,Mode=FindAncestor},Path=MenuClick}"></Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>                    
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </Menu.ItemTemplate>
        </Menu>
    </Grid>
```

In this i have tried to bind the MenuClick(ICommand)  to MenuItem , but it did not bind correctly

I have check the binding in the following forum link

```
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23941314/wpf-how-can-i-create-menu-and-submenus-using-binding?rq=1][1]
```

In this command added in the MenuModel ,  i need to Command in the MenuViewmodel

Answer (score 3):

This way of binding :

```
{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MenuViewModel},     
                                        AncestorLevel=2, Mode=FindAncestor}
```

..is not working, because the `AncestorType` does not derive from `UIElement`.

The Path of the binding should be `DataContext.MenuClick`, and the `AncestorType` should be `Menu`. Putting it all together :

```
<Setter Property="Command" 
        Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.MenuClick, 
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Menu},
                                                       AncestorLevel=2}}">
</Setter>
```

`Mode=FindAncestor` is the default mode, so i left that out.

In the [MSDN: RelativeSource.AncestorType Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource.ancestortype(v=vs.110).aspx) it is only stated that any Type could theoretically be used, however, `FindAncestor` inspects the visual tree to try and find the given ancestor, so whatever type you are looking for must be present in the visual tree. Hope this helps.