# How to expand sub menus from code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

This is XAML codes.

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Menu x:Name="Menu1">
        <MenuItem x:Name="MenuItem1" Height="40" Header="File">
            <MenuItem x:Name="MenuItem11" Header="Help"/>
            <MenuItem x:Name="MenuItem12" Header="About"/>
            <MenuItem x:Name="MenuItem13" Header="Exit"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

How to expand sub menus from code behind?

Question picture: https://prnt.sc/img9p6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a MenuViewModel class that has a ObservalbleCollection of SubMenuViewModel(s).

This class will need a property for the IsOpen for The Menu. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menuitem.issubmenuopen(v=vs.110).aspx

You should not create the MenuItems in WPF. But bind the Itemssource to thies collection.

You then bind the IsOpen from the MenuItem to the MenuItems in WPF (ItemsTemplate)

[WPF - How can I create menu and submenus using binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23941314/wpf-how-can-i-create-menu-and-submenus-using-binding)