# Pure XAML for Menu with ObservableCollection?

Tags: wpf, menu, observablecollection, menuitem, itemsource

This is my ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons;
class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

And i want to create menu with all this `Persons` object from my `List`.

So in `XAML` i just create this:

```
<Menu Name="menuPersons" DockPanel.Dock="Top" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">

</Menu>
```

**Code behind**

```
    MenuItem fileMenuItem = new MenuItem();
    fileMenuItem.Header = "Persons";
    menuPersons.Items.Add(fileMenuItem);

    foreach (Person item in Persons)
    {
          fileMenuItem.Items.Add(new MenuItem
          {
              Header = item.FirstName,
          });
    }
```

But as you can see this looks ugly so my question is is pure `XAML` way to do that and `bind` all my `object` with all its properties ?

**Update**

So the solution works fine for me but i only have one issue:

```
<Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
         <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}"/>
    </Style>
</Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
```

I have `Style` that i am using but so i cannot use this `Menu.ItemContainerStyle`

How can i solve this ? (note that i have another several different `Menus` that i using with this `Style` but i only need this `Command` for this `Menu`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF - How can I create menu and submenus using binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23941314/wpf-how-can-i-create-menu-and-submenus-using-binding)

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate question. Try checking out this URL
[Menus and submenus using Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23941314/wpf-how-can-i-create-menu-and-submenus-using-binding)

Comment: Why i need to MenuItemViewModel class ?

Comment: That is just an example. You can adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Please see my update

Comment: Where is the Command property? Need more code to understand the issue

Comment: "You have a Style..."?. How do you apply this Style?