# How to bind Menu items with observableCollection in xaml and wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I can assign them using  but how to view all the items present in the Observable collection in a view model?

```
 <Menu Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Gray">
            <MenuItem Header="Item Collection">
                <MenuItem Header="Item 1"></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Item 2"></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Sub Items">
                    <MenuItem Header="SubItem 1"></MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Header="SubItem 2"></MenuItem>
                </MenuItem>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
```

View Model contains a simple int type observable collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MenuItems` have an `ItemsSource` property.

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem Header="Item Collection" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemCollection}">
        <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding }"
            </DataTemplate>
        </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23941314/wpf-how-can-i-create-menu-and-submenus-using-binding) for a more complete answer.